# how can i use a string to to represent an sqlalchemy object attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am writing a Flask application with SQLalchemy and WTForms.

Trouble with database updates... I have many object table fields I am trying to update.

so I started with this...

```
# this works great but needs many lines of code
event.evt_num = form.evt_num.data
event.evt_name = form.evt_name.data
event.evt_location = form.evt_location.data
event.evt_address = form.evt_address.data
event.evt_city = form.evt_city.data
event.evt_state = form.evt_state.data
...
```

While the above snippet works, in reality it is huge.  So I would like to be smarter and iterate thru the attributes to update the database.  So I tried the following...

```
event_fields = ('evt_num', 'evt_name', 'evt_location', 'evt_address',
                    'evt_city', 'evt_state', 'evt_zip', 'evt_notes')

for aa in event_fields:
    print "form data", getattr(form, aa).data  # prints posted form data
    print "db data", getattr(event, aa) # prints posted data from database

    if getattr(form, aa).data != getattr(event, aa):  # if form data shows a change
        setattr(event, aa, getattr(form, aa).data)    # update database does not work
        db_change = True
        session.flush()
        ...
```

This line doesnt work to update the database:

```
setattr(event, aa, getattr(form, aa).data)
```

I get this error "**AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'aa'** "

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you store the results of your `getattr()` calls in some variables?  That way, you aren't repeatedly making those calls.  If `event` has the attribute at first, but then suddenly doesn't have it, could you be clearing it from the object when you use the `getattr()` function?  If so, storing the results in a variable should also solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried removing the getattr(form, aa).data from setattr() function and stored that much to a temp variable and it resolved the issue.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you restructured like this?

```
event_fields = ('evt_num', 'evt_name', 'evt_location', 'evt_address',
            'evt_city', 'evt_state', 'evt_zip', 'evt_notes')

for aa in event_fields:
    form_data = getattr(form, aa).data
    db_data = getattr(event,aa)
    print "form data", form_data  # prints posted form data
    print "db data", db_data # prints posted data from database

    if form_data != db_data:  # if form data shows a change
        setattr(event, aa, form_data)    # update database now works
        db_change = True
        session.flush()
        ...
```

This way, you make fewer calls to `getattr()` and maybe optimize your code slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Per user:coralv's comment, I resolved the problem by storing the getattr contents into a variable instead of having it as a part of the setattr function.  Code ends up like this...

```
event_fields = ('evt_num', 'evt_name', 'evt_location', 'evt_address',
                'evt_city', 'evt_state', 'evt_zip', 'evt_notes')

for aa in event_fields:
    print "form data", getattr(form, aa).data  # prints posted form data
    print "db data", getattr(event, aa) # prints posted data from database
    if getattr(form, aa).data != getattr(event, aa):  # if form data shows a change
        val = getattr(form, aa).data
        setattr(event, aa, val)    # update database now works
        db_change = True
        session.flush()
        ...
```