# dynamically insert rows to table flask sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, setattr

I want to insert new rows to an sql table dynamically in SQLAlchemy.

I basically want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369686/how-can-i-use-a-string-to-to-represent-an-sqlalchemy-object-attribute), but instead of doing it with an UPDATE, I want to do it with an INSERT.

I am using Flask and WTForms.

Right now, I have to add a new user doing this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    contact_info = UserContactInfo(street_number=form.street_number.data,
                                   street_address = form.street_address.data,
                                   unit_number = form.unit_number.data
                                  )
    db.session.add(contact_info)
    db.session.commit()
```

I would be able to add new attributes to UserContactInfo alot easier if I could iterate through the Inserts.

I have tried to do it this way, but no change is made to the database.

```
form = ContactInfoForm()
contact_info = UserContactInfo()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    table_obj_members = get_attributes(UserContactInfo())
        for aa in table_obj_members:
             form_data = getattr(form, aa).data
             setattr(contact_info, aa, form_data)

 db.session.commit()
```

I have seen a couple discussions around this and instantiating the whole Class and not the object attribute, but I can't seem to make this apply to this problem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example you forgot to add modified object to the session before commiting.
There is a function in WTForms that does exactly what you describe: `populate_obj()` [[1](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj)].

Example:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    contact_info = UserContactInfo()
    form.populate_obj(contact_info)

    db.session.add(contact_info)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: thanks. that's a handy feature. note i had to add foreign_key and value to database object before populate. `contact_info=UserContactInfo(id=user_id)`